# Is there a Linux platform for creating Machine Learning layers, transforms, testing, and backpropagation

Tags: linux

Is there a flavor of Linux for building neural networks, for layering statistical packages for building and training transformers? Some sort of open source PyTorch or Keros or TensorFlow in OS form where statistical tools and their explanations are in gui?

Comment: that sounds like something that runs *on Linux*, not something that *is Linux*

Comment: I really doubt it, it would be very weird for someone to try and build a whole operating system for this, but to be sure you would have to explain what you need more clearly. Do you just want GUIs for some programs? Do such GUIs exist? And PyTorch, Keras and TensorFlow _are_ open source tools, so that's also confusing.

Comment: In $job-1 the "GNU/Linux Distribution" we where using for this (Machine Learning or AI) was Ubuntu 22.04 LTS when I left in December 22 with Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Excellent point. "It sounds like something that runs on Linux, not something that is Linux." And it is my point exactly. Right now, Linux would be an excellent platform for joining all these tools in a specialized distribution. Do such GUI's exist? Probably not. Should they? Probably so. Not only are PyTorch, Keras and Tensor Flow open source, they are also API so that should make the Linuxx developers job easier, not harder. Lets not forget the Linux objective -- a platform.  That is why there are so many flavors of Linux: to join the tools for a specific objective.